Activity on deleted Discussions is visible
When logged out, I can see the activity entry about a revision to a reply to a deleted Discussion (the reply itself wasn't deleted):

The timeline and revision history for the reply is also still visible to unprivileged users, but they shouldn't be. They should 404 just like when trying to view the same pages on an answer to a deleted question (unless you're the author or a mod).
